# how to get google ranking when changing domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

Our old website has a pretty good ranking for a lot of keywords and other stuff that google likes.
But we have to change our local domain into a .com domain. 
Now I get the question from management: how do we keep our rankings when disable the old domain and active the new .com domain.
The new domain.com is also on a other server.

Are there some tricks for this or do I only have to change the DNS A records to change it to the .com domain and google takes the old data with it?

What if the server provider of the old site does not give ftp access? I have heard from my colleague that ftp is not possible! What to do in that case.
We can move the domain name to our new service provider and then install a .htaccess with redirecting to the new server. Is that a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your old domain must still point to your server in parallel of the new one.

In your `.htaccess` file you have to redirect old domain urls to the new domain with a 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

By changing the domain you will likely lose your backlinks PageRank in Google.

Comment: Florian, does this means that I have to keep the old site a live with only .htaccess active? Or are there more files to keep?

Comment: Any of your files needs to move except if you change your server.
Previously your DNS A records were directing your old domain name to your server. You just need to add a new DNS A record for directing your new domain name to the same server.

And you will keep as long as possible this old domain name directing to your new domain so that external links (blog posts, forums, social network, ...) still works and get redirected to your new domain.

Comment: What if the server provider of the old site does not give ftp access? I have heard from my colleague that ftp is not possible!

Comment: Then your domain name provider might have a DNS redirect option which will do the same thing as the `.htaccess` example given above, a permanent redirect to your new domain.

Comment: I was not sure you were changing your server as well as the domaine name. In this case you will be able to direct the two domain to your new server. You don't need an .htaccess on your old server just on the new one with the above code.

Comment: You will not lose PageRank with a 301 redirect, only the weight of PageRank of external sites (blog posts, forums, social network) that have links to your old domain name. If you have partners website you shall ask them to update the link to new domain name.

Comment: Florian thanks for you ideas and tips. I appreciate it and will use them.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer, or do you need more informations ?

Comment: Florian I have no idea where to accept your answers. Can you give me a link for closing this thread and accepting it as solved by you?

Comment: Next to my answer there's a validate icon in the form of a "v" mark. [how does accepting an answer work ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Finally discover it. Thanks for the tip and your answer/suggestions.